# Как понять что на порту прокси сервер?

Tags: прокси, порты

Доброго времени суток, у меня возник вопрос, есть компьютер, у него открыты некоторые порты, на одном из них висит прокси, как можно понять на каком? Если использовать nmap с banner скриптом, он не возвращает ничего на данном порту, есть ли способ проверить на прокси без попытки его использования как прокси?

Comment: "есть ли способ проверить на прокси без попытки его использования как прокси?" - IMHO нет. Для SOCKS вам нужно будет посылать данные в соответствии с SOCKS-протоколом, а это уже использование его как прокси.

Answer (score 1):

Сервис не обязан сообщать о себе, но если сообщает то это легко проверяется с помощью telnet.

Answer (score 0):

https://2ip.ru/check-port/ - этим, либо любым другим сканером портов. А потом загуглить какие приложения используют открытые порты